# Down voting decreases my rep but not the user with rep = 1?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

When i downvote an answer by a person with rep = 1, SO doesnt reduce the persons rep by 2 but i am still charged for my downvote

Should'nt both these changes be atomic? This would of course involve having a -ve rep value.

If we do not want to have a -ve rep, atleast people downvoting such answers should not get penalized unnecessarily by decreasing their rep, in my opinion.

Can anyone throw any light on the rationale behind the current implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reputation can never go below 1.

Comment: this is specifically for a user with rep = 1. Are you saying if no one else votes, my downvote should make his rep -1? Are -ve reps allowed?

Comment: @insane sorry, I did not see that. Rep can never go below 1. Downvotes are still recorded and will have other .. effects, so they are still useful.